# Using Google App Engine's Cron service to extract data from a URL

Tags: database, google-app-engine, screen-scraping, cron

I need to scrape a simple webpage which has the following text:

Value=29
Time=128769

The values change frequently.

I want to extract the Value (29 in this case) and store it in a database. I want to scrape this page every 6 hours. I am not interested in displaying the value anywhere, I just am interested in the cron. Hope I made sense.

Please advise me if I can accomplish this using Google's App Engine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please advise me if I can accomplish
>   this using Google's App Engine.

Sure!  E.g., in Python, `urlfetch` (with the URL as argument) to get the contents, then a simple `re.search(r'Value=(\d+)').group(1)` (if the contents are as simple as you're showing) to get the value, and a `db.put` to store it.  Do you want the Python details spelled out, or do you prefer Java?

**Edit**: urllib / urllib2 would also be feasible (GAE does support them now).

So `cron.yaml` should be something like:

```
cron:
- description: refresh "value"
  url: /refvalue
  schedule: every 6 hours
```

and `app.yaml` something like:

```
application: valueref
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /refvalue
  script: refvalue.py
  login: admin
```

You may have other entries in either or both, of course, but this is the subset needed to "refresh the value".  A possible `refvalue.py` might be:

```
import re
import wsgiref.handlers

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

class Value(db.Model):
  thevalue = db.IntegerProperty()
  when = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class RefValueHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    resp = urlfetch.fetch('http://whatever.example.com')
    mo = re.match(r'Value=(\d+)', resp.content)
    if mo:
      val = int(mo.group(1))
    else:
      val = None
    valobj = Value(thevalue=val)
    valobj.put()

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [('/refvalue', RefValueHandler),], debug=True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Depending on what else your web app is doing, you'll probably want to move the `class Value` to a separate file (e.g. `models.py` with other models) which of course you'll then have to import (from this `.py` file and from others which do something interesting with all of your saved values).  Here I've taken some possible anomalies into account (no `Value=` found on the target page) but not others (the target page's server does not respond or gives an error); it's hard to know exactly what anomalies you need to consider and what you want to do if they occur (what I'm doing here is very simply recording `None` as the value at the anomaly's time, but you may want to do more... or less -- I'll leave that up to you!-)

Comment: I am interested in Python version, thank you!

I was trying to use urllib2, httplib2. SO urlfetch is the way to go is it? 

The contents are really that simple. Unique variables holding dynamic values.

Value=29 Time=128769 a=39 b=129 c=9 d=12 e=29 f=659 g=279 h=5769 i=43 k=128 j=29 l=769 m=29 n=187

So, The imports should be re and the urlfetch library, is it? I am so sorry, I am a Python newbie, I wish Google App engine supported more languages or better yet an access to Linux terminal!

Comment: @NJTechGuy, GAE does support Java (and indirectly through that many languages that can be implemented on top of Java, such as JRuby, Scala, Groovy, Clojure -- see http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine for a list of 8+ languages known to run on App Engine... are you *seriously* saying that those TEN-plus languages just aren't enough and that's truly limiting you?!-). No idea what "access to Linux terminal" means in this context. Anyway, edited the answer to include a complete solution.

Comment: Oh my god Alex! You are a genius! So many forums out there hate to help newbies. You provided me a full solution! I am yet to test it but I am sure it will work :) 

I never liked Java :( Preferred C# back then. Looks like I have to gain some ground on Java, keep hearing a lot about it! I would love PERL compatibility on GAE. I am kinda new to the open source world, I love it already! With sites like these, I should be on top in no time! Thank you so much :)

Comment: p.s : Is there anyway I could be alerted immediately when an answer is posted/edited? Daily digest works but an instant alert will be awesome! Just a thought!

Comment: I believe you can set up RSS feeds, but I haven't personally done so; check out meta.stackoverflow.com.